# nginx reverse proxy to multiple backend servers depending on URL

Tags: nginx, webserver, reverse-proxy

I have 1 frontend Nginx server and 2 backend nginx servers.

Frontend server does proxy pass to the backend server. Previously there was only 1 backend server so all my queries were going to the single backend server, but as the traffic increased, I have added 1 more backend server just for search queries.

But I can not make only search queries to go to the 2nd backend server.

my current configuration is like this.

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com;

    location /search/ {
        proxy_pass https://search.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host search.example.com;

        #set custom headers for upstream server
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header CF-Connecting-IP "";
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://box1.example.com/;
        proxy_set_header Host box1.example.com;

        #set custom headers for upstream server
        proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
        proxy_set_header CF-Connecting-IP "";
        proxy_ssl_verify off;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;

        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP   $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

What I want to do is.

If URL is

```
https://example.com/search/test/1/8/0
```

then reverse proxy to `search.example.com`

else reverse proxy all other requests to `box1.example.com`

my current configuration gives `404 not found` errors for `search queries`.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Should the upstream URI include the `/search/` prefix, or did you intend to remove it?

Comment: Try with `proxy_pass https://search.example.com;` without the trailing `/`, may be you need to send `/search/` as well. See this article for a good explanation https://tarunlalwani.com/post/nginx-proxypass-server-paths/